# DD4T 2.0 packages for SDL web 8

Tags: dd4t

What are the DD4T2.0 packages have to be installed in content delivery end while upgrading to SDL web 8 from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1?

Comment: Can you be more precise with the CD environment? java or .NET

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about .NET: you can either use the in-process or the REST/CIL provider:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8.CIL

Note that the in-process API is deprecated in SDL Web 8, but it provides the smoothest upgrade path; once you have upgraded to SDL Web 8 in-process and everything works fine, you should migrate to REST/CIL.

Also note that both SDL Web 8 DD4T Providers are currently only available as pre-release (alpha) versions. DXA 1.4 is built on DD4T.Providers.SDL.Web8.CIL (2.0.0.6-alpha) and we didn't encounter any issues during our tests (but note that DXA doesn't cover everything in DD4T).